# Visual Studio 2015 Getting Method add_PropertyChanged in type Namespace_Accessor from assembley does not have implementation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms

I am working on a webform application which I migrated with `Visual Studio 2015` from 4.6.

I am getting the following error:

`Method 'add_PropertyChanged' in type Namespace_Accessor from assembly does not have an implementation`

I also getting `The BuildShadowTask task failed unexpectively`

I did a search for `add_PropertyChanged` nothing shows up.

The Namespace, I found in the WindowService. When I clicked on the Service Reference and when I clicked on any of the property, it takes me to the Reference.cs file. I do see this in the code

`public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

THe `class` inherits from `System.ComponentModel` and see the following as part of the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`

`event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

I googled this issue and people are getting this error because private accessor are deprecated in 2010 and will not build in 2015.

They say remove private via reflection but I am not sure how to do this.

I read an article which looks a lot like my problem but it did not give any details on how to fix this bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2474736/publicize-exe-stopped-working-after-installing-visual-studio-2015

Any help is greatly appreciate to get this build without this error.

Thanks